# description with double quotes

Tags: asp.net, prettyphoto

in asp.net i'm using `ListView` to display products from DB.

all works fine, but i have an anchor using [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) to display description about the product in popup. but i noticed when the description starts or contains double quotes is not showing in my popup!

this is my anchor:

```
<a href="WEBIMAGES/<%#Eval("FirmName")%>/<%# Eval("PicturName") %>" rel="prettyPhoto" title="<%#Eval("FirmName") %>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<%#Eval("ItemName") %>" style="color: #f1652f;vertical-align:bottom;" >More Details</a>
```

i tried to use @ in front of itemName to escape double quotes but not working.

 Anyone had this problem before?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Single Quote to avoid your problem like below

```
<a href="WEBIMAGES/<%#Eval('FirmName')%>/<%# Eval('PicturName') %>" rel="prettyPhoto" title='<%#Eval("FirmName") %>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<%#Eval("ItemName") %>' style="color: #f1652f;vertical-align:bottom;" >More Details</a>
```

Comment: it works perfect, thank you. i had to change the position on single quotes to the title and double for field name

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using single quotes instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quote in your markup as mentioned in the other answer, or you can use the [HtmlEncode method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to encode your quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with double quotes stopping text in a simple popup using 'title='. No answers above helped me! I replaced the double quotes with the HTML & quot ; (no spaces) and that worked for me. Not sure if this will fix you problem but it may help someone else.